# Possibility of using booleans in the query parameter of /search/excerpts

Tags: support, tags, search, api, tag-search

We can use the symbols `;` (respectively `&`) on the `tagged` parameter to represent an AND (respectively an OR) boolean operator on tags. For example, the API call

> [/2.2/search/excerpts?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=fortran;blockchain&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=fortran;blockchain&site=stackoverflow)

returns an empty list since there is no question that is simultaneously tagged with the [fortran] and [blockchain] tags.

Is there a similar way to use boolean operators in the query parameter `q`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `q` parameter roughly supports the same syntax as the search field on the sites, so you can do boolean logic on tags, provided that you use square brackets:

| Query | API search | Site search | Number of results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `[fortran] OR [blockchain]` | [link](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=%5Bfortran%5D%20OR%20%5Bblockchain%5D&filter=!9_bDE.BDp&site=stackoverflow&run=true) | [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfortran%5D+or+%5Bblockchain%5D) | 32512 |
| `[fortran]` | [link](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=%5Bfortran%5D&filter=!9_bDE.BDp&site=stackoverflow&run=true) | [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfortran%5D) | 24711 |
| `[blockchain]` | [link](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=%5Bblockchain%5D&filter=!9_bDE.BDp&site=stackoverflow&run=true) | [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bblockchain%5D) | 7801 |
| `[fortran] [blockchain]` | [link](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=%5Bfortran%5D%20%5Bblockchain%5D&filter=!9_bDE.BDp&site=stackoverflow&run=true) | [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfortran%5D+%5Bblockchain%5D) | 0 |